# UIActivity indicator in UIwebview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

i have seen many tutorials but none of them work:

I have a UIwebView in my storyboard, and it loads the indicated website normally, but it takes time and I would like to use the progress indicator. I have added it to my storyboard, dragged it to the **.h file** (so property...) .
In **.m** I added:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)web1{

[loadingIndicator startAnimatin];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)web1{

[loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

}
```

web1 is the name of my webview. 
It does not work? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine on my project

viewDidLoad :

```
    UIWebView *detailView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(y, x, width, height)];
    detailView.delegate = self;
```

and then

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)web1{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)web1{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;}
```

[EDIT : Interface Builder]

If you are using IB with StoryBoard

First, select your storyboard, an click on the View Controller in the View Controller Scene. Then open the Utilities Pane (on the right) and click on the Identity Inspector to make sure that the class mentioned in the Custom Class section is you web view controller.

[image]

then click on your web view component.
Now open the Utilities Pane (on the right) and click on the Connections Inspector
There should be a section Outlets. In this section click on delegate and drag it to the View Controller in the View Controller Scene like so :

[image]

Then add the webViewDidStartLoad and the webViewDidFinishLoad functions in the view controller implementation file.

It works fine here. Hope it works for you.

Comment: But what does detail View actually do. It is the name of the webview? But I have already created a webview that is called web1. So why do I need to create another webview?

Comment: Do you use Interface Builder to create you're UIWebView or did you create it programmatically ?

Comment: i add the object and drag the blue line to .h

Comment: then be sure to set the delegate to the File's Owner. I'll add a picture to my answer in a minute.

Comment: i am using storyboard though, not nib

Comment: Works fine, thanks a lot. i spent hours trying to solve the problem. An if I want to add an activity indicator in the view, it is the same thing, instead with indicator startAnimating?

Comment: Yes, just put whatever code you need to execute in the webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad functions. Also, don't forget to hide you UIActivityIndicatorView once the web view is loaded..